# Tell this guy to "Duck Off" for all Stack Exchange sites

Tags: support

This annoying guy appeared today first on **Ask Ubuntu** and then on **Unix and Linux**. I had to tell him on both sites to "Go away". Is there a setting to make him go away on **ALL** Stack Exchange sites or do I have to do it one by one?

[image: Overflow Duck.gif]

Comment: I'm pretty sure it'll go away within next 24-36 hours or so! ;-)

Comment: @pomsky so this is just a "one-night stand"? :p

Comment: Have a look at your calendar (and remind yourself of time zones, maybe)...

Comment: @ByteCommander yeah I read the dupe candidate's reference to APRIL FOOLS DAY :)